# Can you use the verb "profile" as a reflexive in the sense 'create an image for oneself'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

As the heading suggests, I'd like to know whether one can use the verb "profile" as a reflexive verb in the sense 'create an image for oneself'; or 'stand out in a specific way'. For instance, if I want to say that there are many ways in which artists can market themselves as a particular kind of artist, with a specific image, can I say:

> There are many ways in which artists can profile themselves.

I have googled it and found some weak support for this use, but what bothers me is that I haven't found any support for it in any of the dictionaries I have checked (Cambridge, Merriam-Webster, Longman, Collins). Is it just a matter of dictionaries lagging behind a bit, or..?

If "profile" can't be used this way, what would you suggest I use instead?

Thank you!

Comment: Just about any English noun can be "verbified" as required, regardless of whether the usage is explicitly defined in dictionaries. [Here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to+profile+himself%22) are plenty of written instances of the sequence ***to profile himself***, showing that the word can definitely be used as a reflexive verb (usually meaning *to create or present a profile of oneself*, where the *exact* sense of "profile" may vary according to context). It''s not that dictionaries "lag" - it's just that they don't always have to include *everything*, no matter how uncommon.

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers! Excellent answer as always! As for whether it should be brought up in dictionaries, I obviously realise dictionaries can't list "everything"; however, if this sense of "profile" is indeed an accepted sense, I think it's lexical and specific enough to merit its own dictionary entry, wouldn't you say? Either way, I'm very grateful for your help! :)

Comment: The full OED includes definition 3c. (transitive) *To give a summary description or make a report of*. I don't think the reflexive form is (yet?) sufficiently common that you'd expect to find it explicitly mentioned in dictionaries - but given the number of online sites where people can fill in their ["profile"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers), that might only be a matter of time.